# Is there a Visual Studio Extension that shows the colors of System.Drawing.Color in the dropdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, system.drawing.color

I find myself looking at the [Microsoft Documentation for System.Drawing.Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/windows-media-center-sdk/bb189018(v=msdn.10)) quite often to see which color I'm getting from which Enum, so I was wondering if there is an Extension which can show a little box with the color next to the string values (I made this with my awesome Paint skills):

[image: System.Drawing.Color]

I found tons of Extensions that show the color in CSS or XAML on the Extension Marketplace, but none that helps with System.Drawing.Color.

Thanks for your help

Comment: resharper does this, See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Color_Assistance.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that this extension has what you want: [Color Picker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.ColorPicker)
This has a tab labeled "Available" which has these colors and their names.  It can also insert the value into your code is one of several formats.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just as **JonasH** said, [Resharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) could realize it. And this is the only one I found to get the answer.

[image]

**And** note that Resharper is not a free extension and new users have a 30-day free usage period.

**If** this still doesn't satisfy you, you should [suggest a feature on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).

**And** when you finishing the ticket, you can share the link here and anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it.

With all of these, I think it will get more attention from **Microsoft** to help us deal with it more quickly.